# tomcat7 maven plugin ignoring configuration

Tags: java, apache, maven, tomcat

my Probelm is, when running mvn tomcat:[re]deploy i get HTTP returncode 403 from `http://localhost:8080/manager`, regardless of what url i specify for the tomcat plugin

I found out in other Questions that

```
<url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
```

should be what i aim for,

but maven completley ignores this xml-tag, it always goes for /manager/deploy, even if i put complete rubbish like,

```
 <url>http://localhost:8080/nana/</url>
```

What i tried:

- Restarting the tomcat,
- checked spelling of url and username/password,
- tomcat is running,
- i can login with the username "mavendeployer" over the gui if i add
  manager-gui as role
- mvn install works fine
- searched the whole Project for occurences of /manager - nothing found (if /nana is put as url)
- removed the `<version>` tag from the tomcat7-plugin in .pom, trying to ensure
  that it was not the version i used that acts funny with my version
  of tomcat

i am using maven 3.0.5, tomcat7, whatever version Maven provides for the plugin

my tomcat-user:

```
    <user username="mavendeployer" 
          password="maven" 
          roles = "manager-script,admin-script" />
```

my maven server-settings:

```
<server>
    <id>localtomcat</id>
     <username>mavendeployer</username>
    <password>maven</password>
</server>
```

my pom: (deleted a lot of dependencies to keep it short, the build works fine, just mvn tomcat:[re]deploy fails:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>net.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>testApp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <!-- <server SW version>-<REST interface version> -->
  <version>1.6.4-1.0.3</version>
  <name>Test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
      ...javax.servlet
      ...javax.servlet.jsp
      ...
         </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>test</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Maven Tomcat Plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <url>http://localhost:8080/nana/</url>
          <server>localtomcat</server>
          <path>/mim</path>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>  
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I don't seem to be able to find a Question where changing url to /manager/text or manager/html did not solve the 403 issue, what am i missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ok, the Solution was very very tricky! The target is not tomcat:[re]depoly, it is tomcat**7**:[re]deploy^^, thanks anyway

Comment: Hilarious - I didn't even think to ask what Maven command you were running! :)

Comment: I was having this exact same problem.  Thanks to your question and answer I now have the exact same solutions.  Up votes all around for you sir.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me:

My `tomcat-users.xml` - **Note the role element**:

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <user username="mavendeployer" password="maven" roles="manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

My `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
  <finalName>your_web_app_name</finalName>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <server>localtomcat</server>
        <update>true</update>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Your Maven `settings.xml` seems fine to me.

If this still doesn't work, let me know and I'll look for other settings/configuration.

Comment: no, removing the <path> tag didn't work and i jsut forgot to post the role elements, they are both there (manager- and admin-script).
Still 403 response from /manager/deploy, regardless of url tag content :/